# Ansible authentication on Windows

Tags: windows, ansible, robocopy, nas

I'm using Jenkins to run ansible playbook on windows host. I'm trying to do a very simple command like `robocopy` between NAS share and local directory on the windows. Problem is that all the time I'm receiving `ACCESS DENIED(5)`. This is not true because user (`domain\sysansible`) on which I'm running ansible already have full rights. There is no problem when I start the same command on windows or any machine. I have noticed that when Jenkins is running the ansible playbook it is being recognized not as a `domain\sysansible` but as a member of local admin group `windows_host\administrator` which doesn't have right to NAS share (and they cannot have because only domain accounts are approved).

My inventory file looks as follow:

```
[application_host]
lizard ansible_host=windows_host.domain.companynet.net ansible_connection=winrm ansible_winrm_transport=kerberos ansible_user=sysansible@company.com ansible_password=***** ansible_port=5986 ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

My ansible task is quite simple. It works when I have exchanged source to a local directory instead of `\\nas-share\applications\app-home`. I have also use somekind of variation of robocopy parameters but also they failed.

```
- name: Sync the contents of home directory to backup site, including subdirectories
  win_command: robocopy \\nas-share\applications\app-home d:\application\backup\home-folder /E /w:5 /r:2 /log:D:\Applications\log.txt /XD \\nas-share\applications\app-home\artifacts
    register: info_robocopy
  tags:
    - robo
```

The problem for me is why I'm being recognized as a local admin account group? How to be recognized on windows as `domain\sysansible`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using basic authentification, it does not allow you to delegate credentials to next host you want to copy files to.

(see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html)

Try to use CredSSP connections to your hosts or establish Kerberos connection with following (example) variable in inventory:

```
ansible_user = user@yourdomain
ansible_password = Passwordthere
ansible_port =5985
ansible_connection = winrm
ansible_winrm_transport = kerberos
ansible_winrm_message_encryption = auto

ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation = yes
```